# how to search protein data bank using author's full name (no initials)

Tags: python

I am trying to search the protein data bank with author's name, but the only choice is to use full last name and initials, therefore there are some false hits. Is there a way to do this with python? Below is the code I used:

```
    import urllib2

#http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do#search

url = 'http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search'

queryText = """

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
  <queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.AdvancedAuthorQuery</queryType>
  <description>Author Name: Search type is All Authors and Author is Wang, R. and Exact match is true</description>
    <searchType>All Authors</searchType>
    <audit_author.name>Wang, R. </audit_author.name>
    <exactMatch>true</exactMatch>
</orgPdbQuery>
"""


print "query:\n", queryText

print "querying PDB...\n"

req = urllib2.Request(url, data=queryText)

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

result = f.read()


if result:

    print "Found number of PDB entries:", result.count('\n')
    print result
else:

    print "Failed to retrieve results"enter code here
```

Comment: Well you could loop through `A.` to `Z.`, then try `A.A.` to `Z.Z.`, etc.  See [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  But it's probably faster to not use an exact match and then filter out the ones you don't need using a regular expression.

Comment: Is there a way to do *what*? If the database does not contain the first name of the author then no, there is no way to get that out of that particular database.

Comment: I meant "is there a way to search with full name", not only using full last and first initial. There is a way to search with full names I think, that I could download all PDB entries and store them in my local drive and then I could search the full name in the header info for all entries, which will take quite some time.

Comment: Thanks, Rufflewind. I think I can first filter out those with (last name + first initial), and then use RE to further select from there. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

PyPDB can perform an advanced search of the RCSB Protein Data Bank by author, keyword, or subject area. The repository is [here](https://github.com/williamgilpin/pypdb) but it can also be found on PyPI:

`pip install pypdb`

For your application, I'd suggest first doing a general keyword search for PDB IDs with the author's name, and then search the resulting list of PDBs for entries containing the author's name among the metadata:

The keyword search for "actin network"

```
from pypdb import *

author_name = 'J.A. Doudna'    
search_dict = make_query(author_name)
found_pdbs = do_search(search_dict)
```

Now iterate through the results looking for the author's name

```
matching_results = list()
for pdb_id in found_pdbs:
    desc_pdb = describe_pdb(item)
    if author_name in desc_pdb['citation_authors']:
        matching_results.append(pdb_id)
```

You can imagine using fancier regular expressions to improve slight variations in the way an author's name or initials are used. There also might be a nicer way to write this code that bundles requests.